# Does the dictionary always map the bulk operator to the CFT operator?

Tags: operators, quantum-gravity, conformal-field-theory, ads-cft

Using the (extrapolate) dictionary, one can map a bulk field to a boundary CFT operator. The mapped operator is always a CFT operator? How is it guaranteed?

Comment: What's the extrapolate dictionary?

Comment: @RyanThorngren Suppose r is a radial direction in AdS and r to infinity is a boundary. r^\Delta \phi equals to O is what the extrapolate dictionary states, where \phi is a bulk field and O is a boundary CFT operator. \Delta is the scaling dimension of O.

Comment: I am talking about the classical limit of AdS/CFT.

Comment: I think I still don't understand your question. Isn't every field on the boundary a CFT operator? Possibly there are some bulk fields (eg. massive ones) with faster than algebraic decay towards the boundary which map to the zero operator.

Comment: @RyanThorngren To be honest, I’m not sure with the concrete definition of CFT operators. All QFT operators seem to be CFT operators (primaries and descendants) in the derivative expansion. But then, even the bulk fields become CFT operators and that is weird, isn’t it?

Answer (score 0):

That is the meaning of AdS/CFT -- that for a given bulk field $\Phi $ has a dual CFT operator $\mathcal{O}_{\Phi }$ in the boundary CFT. In particular, the question you are asking is the retro-construction of bulk reconstruction from the extrapolate dictionary (referred to as the HKLL prescription). Now, as you noted, the extrapolate dictionary is
\begin{equation}
\lim _{r\to \infty }r^{\Delta }\Phi (r, x)=\mathcal{O}_{\Phi }(x)\;,
\end{equation}
and one can find a corresponding "smearing" function to reconstruct the bulk field by inverting the representation for the (let's say free) field, something like
\begin{equation}
\Phi =\int dx \;K(X, x)\mathcal{O}_{\Phi }(x)\;.
\end{equation}
Without going into details, the answer is that you can find the bulk field from the CFT operator -- however, this is a complicated task with some subtleties with the $1/N$ expansions, but one that can be done nonetheless.